# PHP - How to stop a while loop when the count is above the number 3

Tags: php

```
         while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                $count++;
                if ($count === 1) {
                    echo $count * $args['posts_per_page'] + $count; ?>
                    <div class="column small-12">
                        <div class="panel-brown">
                            <img src="" alt="" />
                            <h5 class="heading-white"><a href="#"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <div class="para-white">
                                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }
                echo $count;
                // 2 < 3
                // 3 < 3
                while ($count <= 3) { ?>
                    <p>
                        hello world
                    </p>
            <?php }

            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This code creates an infinity loop which is clearly not what I wanted to do.

The intended behaviour is when count gets over 3 then it stops outputting hello world. I've read up on break while loops however don't understand php enough to make this work.

Let me know your thoughts on best practice to get this done.

Comment: `$count` never changes..

Comment: It does let me update my code sorry

Comment: First write down what value you get from `echo $count;` before your loop. Then go through your while loop body and write down each iteration how the condition looks like: `$count <= 3`

Comment: Still the same  - your `$count` value never changes in a `while` loop.

Comment: So I need to add $count++ to the while loop as well?

Comment: If value `$count` is `2` and it __NEVER__ changes, when will your `while` loop stops?

Comment: why didn't you just use a `for` loop here?

Comment: actually the line `while ($count <= 3)` I think you should have said `if($count <= 3)` because this is already inside a while loop that *is* incrementing `$count`.